# Как разместить гостей в отелях (сервис похожий на booking.com)?

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм, поиск

Хочу создать сервис похожий на booking.com. Структура базы данных приведен ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть отели - hotel. Есть типы номеров отелей - hotel_room. По количеству взрослых и детей размещенных в комнате меняется и стоимость номера - hotel_room_price. Есть таблица свободных номеров предоставленных отелем по дате - hotel_room_accommodation.

Нужно вывести список соответствующих отелей и самый выгодной вариант размещения гостей по заданному количеству взрослых, детей, количеству номеров в заданной промежутке времени.

Вопрос для меня получился очень сложным. Прошу высказать свои мнении как можно решить такой вопрос.

Comment: Сразу вопрос - а вы пробовали декомпозировать задачу ? если данная задача слишком сложна - разбейте ее на под задачи. У вас есть несколько критериев выборки. Начните с одной из них - а именно с даты, точнее промежутка времени. Т.е. первым шагом станет поиск всех доступных отелей на период от х до y. А это уже гораздо проще - это один селект с where.

Comment: Ну и еще вопрос - что именно не получается ? Написать на sql ? написать на php запросы к бд ?

Comment: Что не получается. Не знаю как нужно подходить к вопросу.
Да. Я пробовал разбить вопрос на части.

Comment: 1. Можно  ли вообще разместить этих гостей в этом отеле.
2. Можно ли разместить гостей в заданных количествах номеров в этих отелях. Если да выводит стоимость. 
3. Если нет выводит оптимальнуию версию.

Comment: Найти доступных номеров в заданном промежутке как вы отметили относительно просто

Comment: Дальше идти пока что не получается.
Предпочтительно использовать меньшее количество запросов к базе данных и большую часть проблемы  решить в базе.

Comment: Сначала решите задачу неоптимально - не все решения приходят сразу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57042/discussion-between-nagiyevel-and-alexoander).